# How do I reference a listbox to a specific sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have an excel file with 2 worksheets (Sheet 1 and Sheet 2) and a userform with a listbox. The listbox should pull 2 columns from sheet 2 but it always pull the columns from sheet 1.

I am using the following code:

```
ListBox1.RowSource = “A2:B50“
```

I tried:

```
ListBox1.RowSource = “Sheet2!A2:B50“
```

but get an

> Runtime error 380 code. Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value.

How do I fix that?

Comment: And what was the error text after that code? Did you really use the quotation marks as you shown for the code that fails?

Comment: Hi,it‘s „Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value“

Comment: (Sigh!) And what might your answer be to my second question (about the quotation marks)?

Comment: Hi it's this, sorry: ListBox1.RowSource = “Sheet2!A2:B50“ but I still get the Runtime error 380 code.

Comment: So, something is different from what @Harun presents in his answer. Did you try that?

Comment: @Frank One thing! Did you set `Column Count` property to 2?

Answer (score 0):

Following code just work fine for me.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet2!A2:B10"
End Sub
```

[image]

When open form shows like...

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why, I still get the run time error. I used your code Harun.

Comment: Once again, did you set column count property value 2?

Comment: Yes, i have column count property on 2. if I chose sheet 2 as an active window and remove the Sheet2! in the rowSource the list appears, but when i add the sheet2! the error code appears.

Comment: @Frank can you share your workbook via google drive or dropbox and put link here. We will check your code.